# Python 'timestamp' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql

I have some data in excel that I want to insert into a MySQL table. 
I read the excel into a Dataframe.
The data includes a date column with dates which I convert to datetime to match the MySQL table setup (the date column is of type datetime).
When I try to insert the data into the table I get the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing
>   format-parameters; Python 'timestamp' cannot be converted to a MySQL
>   type

When I print out the date after converting it I do get it in the 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format that seems to be the format MySQL requires?

> 2011-05-10 00:00:00

Probably doing something simple wrong, but can't get this to work. Any suggestions?

The SQL of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Weight` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Weight` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c
```

My Python script, a bit extended to incorporate some dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np

#import csv in dataframe
#df = pd.read_excel('/excel.xlsx')
#dataframe for this question on stackoverflow
startDate = '2011-05-03'
dateList = pd.date_range(startDate, periods=1000).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': dateList,
                'Weight': np.random.normal(loc=68, scale=10, size=(1000,))
              })
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'],errors='raise')

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="host",
    user="user",
    port="port",
    passwd="Password",
    database="database_name"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO Weight (Date, Weight) values (%s, %s)"

for index, row in df.iterrows() :
    val = (row['Day'], row['Weight'])
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

To be clear, it fails on the *execute(sql, val)* part

Comment: Have you tried to use [`df.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)? It should be able to take care of this kind of issues. If it works it will even be faster than manually iterating over the dataframe and executing the same query over and over again

Comment: @DeepSpace excellent! That works and is much better indeed! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using df.to_sql as suggested by @DeepSpace solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another more simple way is replacing date format to text in excel file.
Use Find/Replace:
Find: 2011
Replace: '2011

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows() :
    ts = row['Day']
    ts = datetime(ts.year, ts.month, ts.day...) # ts.hour/min/sec if you have time info as well
    val = (ts, row['Weight'])
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

you need to convert pandas Timestamp to python datetime dtype!