# timestamp object cannot be converted to MYSQL type

Tags: python, datetime, mysql-connector, string-to-datetime

I have a dataframe with string dates
I convert them to datetime time using **pd.to_datetime()**

then when I create insedrt query and make cursor.execute() it returns this error to me

"mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'timestamp' cannot be converted to a MySQL type "

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

for i,row in df.iterrows():

                    sql="INSERT INTO db.datestable (Date,Name) VALUES (%s,%s);"
                    
my_cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
```

Comment: Why don't yo use `df.to_sql` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 'timestamp' cannot be converted to a MySQL type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062493/python-timestamp-cannot-be-converted-to-a-mysql-type)

Comment: Or convert the value to `datetime.datetime` in the loop.

Comment: The error complains about the Pandas [Timestamp type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html). You can use [to_pydatetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html) to convert Timestamp values to Python datetime, but using `to_sql` with `if_exists='append` is almost always better than manually executing 100s of INSERTs

Comment: I'm not using df.to_sql because sometimes I need to check duplicates to udapted changed records in the table

Comment: How can I convert it in the loop ?

Comment: Your code isn't checking duplicates though. The duplicate shows how to do it and I posted a link to `to_pydatetime`. Instead of `tuple(row)` use the actual fields, eg `tuple(row['Date'].to_pydatetime(), row['Name'])`

Comment: It's possible to make `to_sql` update existing rows, as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891952/134204). A faster and more scalable solution would be to insert the data into a staging table and then upsert to the target table. This way, instead of eg 500 individual UPDATEs you'd have a batched insert to the staging table, 1 INSERT with the new data and 1 UPDATE over the existing. Or one INSERT that updates duplicates

Answer (score -2):

pd.to_datetime() function is converting dates to Python datetime objects, which cannot be directly inserted into a MySQL database. Convert this datetime to mysql compatible date string before insertion.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

for i,row in df.iterrows():
   # Convert the datetime object to a MySQL-compatible date time string
      date_str = row['Date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sql = "INSERT INTO db.datestable (Date,Name) VALUES (%s,%s);"
                    
my_cursor.execute(sql, (date_str, row['Name']))
```

Comment: That's simply wrong. MySQL (the database) *does* support strongly typed parameters. MySQL Connector does support `datetime`. So does SQLAlchemy, which Pandas uses to store dataframes to databases

Comment: The error complains about [Pandas' Timestamp type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), not the use of date parameters